# Flex: How to call an actionscript function from htmlText anchor

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, textarea, htmltext

Is there any way to call an action script function from an anchor which defined in TextArea component's htmlText property.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got the answer [here](http://blog.circlecube.com/2008/12/portfolio/asfunction-texteventlink-tutorial-for-as3-flash-html-link-to-call-actionscript-function-tutorial/)..

Answer (score 5):

If this anchor is an href from an  tag, you can dispatch events and handle them like that:

```
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function linkHandler(e:TextEvent):void
        {
            if (e.text == "test")
                trace("test called")
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:creationComplete>
    <![CDATA[
        textArea.htmlText="<a href='event:test'>Link!</a>";
    ]]>
</mx:creationComplete>

<mx:TextArea id="textArea" link="linkHandler(event)" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The ExternalInterface class will provide you with a communication channel between Javascript and Actionscript.  Using this class, you can listen for calls from the page's Javascript, as well as, dispatch messages and data back.

The links below are referencing AS 3.0.  Hope that helps!

[ExternalInterface Docmentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)

[Usage Description](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00000340.html)

[Sample Code](http://flexion.wordpress.com/2007/08/21/external-interface-tip/)

Comment: browser may not be support for external function, or javascript could be disabled..