# AS3 function call from dynamic textfield

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to call an as3 function from a dynamic textfield.

I've tried this:

```
function showPopupWindow(){
    trace("it works");
}

var texts="Hello world. <a href='#' onclick='showPopupWindow()'><u>This is a function call</u></a>";

text_txt.htmlText = texts;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex: How to call an actionscript function from htmlText anchor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/871325/flex-how-to-call-an-actionscript-function-from-htmltext-anchor)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to use the `TextEvent.LINK` event. First, you'll need to create a link that points  to a URL Flash can recognize by prepending `event:` to a name. For example, you might have a piece of text like this:

```
textField.htmlText = "<a href='event:playMovie'>Play.</a><br />" + 
                     "<a href='event:stopMovie'>Stop.</a>";
```

Then, you need to add a listener for the event. You can use the `TextEvent::text` property to determine what link was clicked. Using the above code, here's a sample handler:

```
textField.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, handleLink);

function handleLink(evt:TextEvent):void {
    switch (evt.text) {
        case "playMovie":
            play();
            break;
        case "stopMovie":
            stop();
            break;
    }
}
```